# Remove a particular pattern from string in shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, sh

The original string is (according to my format)

> "cf foo -J 12345 -z -macro TEST_IFDEFINE -macro
>   THIS -macro THIS1 -macro THIS2"

In order to pass it to another script, I am trying to modify it into

> "cf foo -J 12345 -z"

To achieve this I have written shell script as follows:

```
string="cf foo -J 12345 -z -macro TEST_IFDEFINE -macro THIS -macro THIS1 -macro THIS2"
done=0
config="-cf"
name=""
for name in $string
do
  if [ $done -eq 1 ];then
    string=`echo $string | sed s/"-macro"//g`
    string=`echo $string | sed s/"$name"//g`
    echo "----->name: $name"
    macro_name="$macro_name -d $name"
    done=0
    echo "----->string: $string"
  fi
  if [ "$name" = "-macro" ];then
    done=1
    macro_def=1
  fi
done
```

From this code I am getting output is :

> cf foo -J 12345 -z 1 2

Here, **$name** contains **THIS1** and **THIS2**. But in script when I do

> | sed s/"$name"//g`

it removes only

> 'THIS'

But keeping

> 1  2

along with original string.
This means script is discarding only alphabets not numeric values in $name.
Suggest me something to achieve this.

Comment: what is the logic in the cleaning of the string? Keep the first 5 words? Everything up to `macro`?

Comment: No... the logic is remove a string "-macro" and followed by macro name. In this case it is "-macro THIS -macro THIS1 -macro THIS2"

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove all the blocks of `-macro WORD`, just say so:

```
$ sed 's/\s-macro \S*//g' <<< "cf foo -J 12345 -z -macro TEST_IFDEFINE -macro THIS -macro THIS1 -macro THIS2"  | cat -vet -
cf foo -J 12345 -z$
```

- `\s-macro \S*` matches `space` + `-macro` + space + `a word`.
- `sed 's/something//g'` removes this `something` as many times as it occurs in the string.

Comment: Not all `sed` dialects accept the Perl regex `\s` but any reasonably modern `sed` should understand the *de facto* synonym `[[:space:]]` and orthogonally `[^[:space:]]` for `\S`.

Answer (score 2):

With extended patterns enabled, you can use a single parameter expansion.

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ foo="cf foo -J 12345 -z -macro TEST_IFDEFINE -macro THIS keepme -macro THIS1 -macro THIS2 keepme"
$ echo "${foo//-macro +([[:alnum:]_])}?( )"
cf foo -J 12345 -z keepme keepme2
```

`+([[:alnum:]_])` matches one or more letters, numbers, or `_`, which I assume to be the definition of a macro name. `?( )` removes the optional trailing space following a macro name. (Optional in the sense that a final `-macro` won't have a space after it.)